# what is the equivalent of ExpectedConditions.not in Python

Tags: python, selenium, appium, wait

In Java one can use ExpectedConditions.not to wait until element is no longer visible or no longer can be found

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.not(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("id1"))));
```

What is pythonic way to do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to wait until element **not** (no more) clickable, try

```
wait.until_not(ExpectedConditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"id1")));
```

P.S. You should remember that element could be initially not clickable after page loaded

Answer (score 0):

Another way

```
wait.until(
    ExpectedConditions.none_of(
        ExpectedConditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "id1"))
    )
)
```